# jQuery conflict in time picker

Tags: jquery

I have two js files and having conflict in implementation.
Order of my links is:

```
     <script language="javascript" src="../js/time.js"></script>     
      <script language="javascript" src="../js/time_picker_min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/json.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" ></script>
```

order of calling on page  is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          <?php $check = ronly($_SESSION['num']);?>
           var myvar= '<?php echo $check; ?>';
        var table = 'prel';
         var id = '<?php echo $_SESSION['num'];?>';

         loadJson(table, id, myvar);
         showhide();
    });
 </script>
 <script language="javascript">
    window.addEvent("domready", function (){

        var tp1 = new TimePicker('time1_picker', 'preltemph', 'time1_toggler', {imagesPath:"../images"});


    });
</script>

 <input type="text" name="preltemph" id="preltemph" /> <a href="#"                          id="time1_toggler">Temp</a>
<div id="time1_picker" class="time_picker_div"></div>
```

If I am using time picker on seperate page without any other Jquery it is working fine. But not while using with others. Time picker is mootool.

How to resolve conflict between these two.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try `jQuery.noConflict()` both mootools and jQuery use `$()` for selecting the elements and this makes conflict between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to look at jQuery.noConflict()

From this site http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Comment: :$.noConflict(); not working for me as its disabling both functionalities. I am using nogray time picker. Its so nice i want to use it but either timepicker is working or other things . Thank u for helping

Comment: @user1482515 this is one of the solution from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ . Please read and try other ones…

Comment: @Paddy: Thanks all. Using other widget without conflict thank you

Comment: @Shikiryu: Thank you . Now using other widget without conflict

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" ></script>
```

to the top of all scripts like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" ></script>
<script language="javascript" src="../js/time.js"></script>     
<script language="javascript" src="../js/time_picker_min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/json.js"></script>
```